# Sending daily email from Excel to Outlook - include PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm trying to set-up a macro that simply sends an email containing two pivot tables that are located on the same sheet.

The current code I'm using doesn't include the table headers. How can I change this?

Side Note:
To send this daily, I figured I could extract the the VBA code to a .vbs file and have it run everytime the computer is turned on. Would this work if the excel file is located in a share drive?

Here's what is being sent to my email:
[image]

Here's what I want to be sent:
[image]

Here's my current code for sending the email.

```
    'Expired & Warning Updates
'Functions:
' Send daily email with expired and almost-expired digsafes

'Sends email once called
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection

    Set rng = Sheets("EXPIRED_LIST").Range("A6:F300").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "address@test.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Daily Dig-safe Update"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid and didn't realize my range was off by one row. Fixed the issue. Now it's time for me to figure out how to have it send an email daily.

Comment: Ron de Bruin's website has some great material for this https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm